# Can I discard a specific X509 signature from file?

Tags: signature, certificates

I'm writing a program to sign files using X.509 certificates and .NET framework classes. My users can sign the same file more than once without any problem (like a revision process). So, a file may contain one or more signatures.

I'm using the [CMSSigner class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.cmssigner) and I don't encrypt the file. I just sign it.

But now a user asked me the following: *"By mistake I signed a file and I would like to take off my signature from that file. Can I do this?"*

I see no problem when the file has only that one user's signature (*only one X509 certificate within*). But I'm not sure if I can unsign the file if it has many signatures there. The routine that I use to strip a signature from a file picks the original data and, in that case, I lose *all* of its signatures.

So, using .NET classes ([X509Certificate2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2)), can I just delete the user's signature from that file, without loss the other certificates there?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Off topic, but: Have you considered using regular source code version control (e.g. Git) alongside your custom signing process?

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff, my code is the recommended code by Microsoft and is functioning perfectly. And I need to keep the default-signature layout (PKCS#7) in these files once they need be validated in other softwares.

Comment: Have you tried? As long as you keep to the given CMS structure and don't wrap one CMS structure within the other you should be able to removed SignedInfo structures.

Comment: This is more an implementation question for StackOverflow I guess. That you can remove signatures from CMS seems clear from the standard.

Comment: Hi @MaartenBodewes, thanks for your comments. I didn't see in the CMS class how remove only one signature from a signed-by-many-guys file. I can recover the original data (no signatures at all), but not how detect some signature and take it off alone.

Comment: Just to make it clear: the file is signed for different people in different computers and days. I can detect the whole existent signatures there.

Comment: Does a signature also cover other people's signatures (if they have signed before you)?

Comment: @SEJPM, I really don't know if a newer signature covers all older, but I guess that yes. I'm using the .NET Signer function to sign the files - and they are not a countersignatures but people signing, at different moments, the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cryptographically speaking, a digital signature provides the property of non-repudiation -- the signer cannot deny signing once signed. So, you either have to keep the unsigned version if you can't strip the signature from the document, or sign another document invalidating the previous signature if the previous document has been released.

Comment: That being said, digital signatures are permanent.

Comment: the process is done this way:  1) Alice signs the file.  2) Bob can revise the "opened version" of that file but cannot change a letter there. Once he decides to sign/agree with its contents, it signs the "closed/signed version" and his signature is appended to the file. I understood your point-of-view but, technically, can I remove a CMS/Signer-Class signature from a file without broke it?

Comment: To be honest, I've never used that CMS/Signer-Class you mentioned, and may be you can provide me with a link to the API and I can have a look at.

Comment: But, if the signature is appended, then it can be removed LIFO (last-in-first-out). What you'll need to know, is the format and structure of the signature.

Comment: The link is above - in question - and you're right: I can't remove older or aleatoric signatures in file without broke it. Only the last one can be removed and my software must ensure that the deletion is performed only by the signature owner. Thank you!